# SQL divide by zero error, nullif not helping

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out this statement but can't get anywhere.

From what I have found so far, I think I need to use an `nullif` clause for each divisor, but when I try and do this it still does not work.

Here is the statement with no `nullif`'s that produces a divide by zero error.

```
(1 - (1 - (x1.hup / (x1.hup / (x1.dp / 100)))) / (1 - (x2.sdp / 100)))
```

Comment: what if `x2.sdp` is 100? then you have `(1 - (100 / 100)` which is 0 and will be the divisior afterwards

Comment: Your formula can be shortened to x1.dp / (100 - x2.sdp), if I'm not mistaken. This removes x1.hup completely and you'd only have to check whether x2.sdp is 100. Maybe you've made a mistake in your formula.

Answer (score 2):

There may be simpler ways to express this.  I think this is all you need:

```
(1 - (1 - (x1.hup / (x1.hup / nullif(x1.dp / 100, 0)))) / nullif(1 - (x2.sdp / 100)), 0))
```

Comment: `x1.hup` could be zero as well. I wonder what the expression is supposed to solve, because it looks quite crazy :D

Comment: I am starting to think my formula may be the problem.. :)... x1.hup = 395.42, x1.dp = 50, x2.sdp = 10 and the answer i am looking for is 44.44.....

Comment: @S.Carter . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want the calculation to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

**This is Not the Answer**

Create a function to  check `zero`  like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsZero] (
    @Number FLOAT,
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN

    IF (@Number = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Number = 1
    END

RETURN (@Number)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but will do the job.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (1 - (x2.sdp / 100) = 0 THEN NULL
            WHEN (x1.dp / 100) = 0 THEN NULL
            WHEN (x1.hup / (x1.dp / 100)) = 0 THEN NULL
            WHEN (x1.hup / (x1.hup / (x1.dp / 100))) = 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE (1 - (1 - (x1.hup / (x1.hup / (x1.dp / 100)))) / (1 - (x2.sdp / 100)))
            END AS field
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Coalescing to zero isn't the magic bullet you're looking for.

Just try to the simplify your problem; if you have `42 / x` and `x` is `null`, replacing it with zero will just result in a division error.

I don't know about the formula you are applying in this case, but the main thing you are lacking is validation. In my example above, if `x` equals to 0 we've got a problem.

Similarly, in `23 / (100 - x)`, `x` can't ever be 100, so you must check that beforehand and handle the situation accordingly. No expression can result in 0 if it`s a divisor.

So, try to establish which **constraints** should be watched before processing; for instance, your statement must not accept 0 for `x1.dp` or `x1.hup`, and `x2.sdp` can be anything but 100 (`1 - 100/100 = 0`, right?). Should one of these situations happen, you could return an error or something.

Comment: You misunderstood the question, I think. NULLIF could turn a zero divisor into null thus rendering the complete calculation null, which is obviously what the OP wants. The question is more or less were to place NULLIF such that it deals with all cases where a divisor can be null.